# How to use if-else statements after picking a random number

Tags: robotframework

I'm able to pick a random number from a list but now I don't know how to use the if-else statement so that it should match to condition to get further details with that number.

I tried doing it with "Run Keyword If" command but it didn't work out for me. Also tried using "For loop" as well and it didn't work out as well.

```
*** Variables ***
@{PARTY}  ABC  XYZ  RTY  DOG

*** Test Cases ***
View all Details
    ${value} =  Evaluate  random.choice($PARTY)  random
    input text  ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${value}
    log to console  \nvalue: ${value}
    click element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
    :for  ${ELEMENT}  IN  @{PARTY}
    \ log  ${ELEMENT}
    \ run keyword if  '@{ELEMENT}' == 'ABC'
    \ ...  else if  '@{ELEMENT}' == 'XYZ'
    \ ...  else if  '@{ELEMENT}' == 'RTY'
    \ ...  else  '@{ELEMENT}' == 'DOG'
```

Expected Result: Now when the random value is picked, the value should be compared with the list and when the condition is true, then I should be able to click that element to get further details of that party.

Actual Result: Random value is picked & FOR loop contains no keywords.

Answer (score 3):

You have several issues.

1. You use a list varibale `@{ELEMENT` for comparison instead of a scalar one.
2. In your `Run Keyword If` statement you have no keyword to run if the condition is true. The same for `ELSE IF` lines.
3. `else if` should be capitalized since it is a reserved keyword.
4. `ELSE` needs no condition at all, it handles all case which are not handled by the previous conditions.
5. You pick a random `${value}` but don't use it. Iterating over a list will give you every condition `true` once.

If you want to use a random value, you don't need a for-loop at all. The code should look like this:

```
View all Details
    ${ELEMENT} =  Evaluate  random.choice($PARTY)  random
    log  ${ELEMENT}
    Run Keyword If  '${ELEMENT}' == 'ABC'   Your Keyword One Here
    ...  ELSE IF  '${ELEMENT}' == 'XYZ'   Your Keyword Two Here
    ...  ELSE IF  '${ELEMENT}' == 'RTY'  Your Keyword Three Here
    ...  ELSE    Your Keyword Four Here
```

Comment: Thanks... Tried going through your code and got stuck. After picking the random value it's comparing it with the ELSE keyword not with ELSE IF. Another thing is after comparing how should I be able to use "click element" command
```````
Search Party By Name                                           | FAIL |
No keyword with name ''XYZ' == 'DOG'' found.

Comment: It's impossible to say anything without seeing the code.